# how compare row by row matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, compare, equality

I have a situation like this

I have data
M size (x by 2)
where data were in already in classify group by

```
C = unique(M(:) , 'rows'); %result will be in g-by-2
```

now I want to assign the data group M accord to C

by creating a R matrix size M-by-1.

Example

```
M = [ 1 2;
      3 3;
      1 2;
      1 5;
      . . ];

assume I got 3 groups 
C = [ 1 2;
      3 3;
      1 5];

I want R to be like
R = [ 1;
      2;
      1;
      3;
      . ];
```

I try to use loop for and find to compare all group

```
for i = 1:size(C(1)
    find(M(:) == C(i,:));
end
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Have another read of [the documentation for `unique`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), specifically the _third_ output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are using the input argument `M(:)`, this is no longer a matrix. Use `[A,B,C]=unique(M , 'rows')` instead.

Besides this the order of your expected output requires the option `'stable'`

Answer (score 2):

No need to find the group numbers. You should do this:

```
 M = [ 1 2;
      3 3;
      1 2;
      1 5;
      ];

[CC,ia,ic] = unique(M,'rows')

CC =

     1     2
     1     5
     3     3


ia =

     3
     4
     2


ic =

     1
     3
     1
     2
```

**ic** is what you are looking for.